# Invalid characters in sqlite query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having issues creating a valid sql query.

Im trying to check if a value, `title` is present in my db.

Here is the method in my adapter class that creates the query.

```
public Cursor byTitle(String title) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_URL
                    }, 
                    "title" + "=" +title, 
                    null,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
 }
```

And its called onClick with

```
  holder.fb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final FDBAdapter db = new FDBAdapter(ctx);
        title = holder.itemName.getText().toString();
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.byTitle(title);
        if (c.getCount()>0) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "yup! " + c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "nope! " + holder.itemName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
  });
```

My error is 
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Rootz": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT url FROM favs WHERE title=[Guide] Rootz Wiki's List of ROMs / Kernels / Tweaks / Theme's / Radios LTE Edition`

I've tried putting quotes around `title` like `"\""+title+"\""` but that wasn't working for me either. How can I make this a valid db query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, might work.

```
  Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_URL
                    }, 
                    "title=?", 
                    title,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Can you explain the query to me though? What does =? signify? Is that jsut checking its existence?

Comment: question mark indicates that the value will be given in selectionArgs rather than inn selection itself. You can bunch together any number of ? and give them in selectionArgs

Comment: actually i was wrong, i mistyped the code and it was just returning negative each time. with your code example, its not valid java.

my `title` is one string. [Guide] Rootz Wiki's List of ROMs / Kernels / Tweaks / Theme's / Radios LTE Edition and is declared as a String multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with SQLite, but I'd try single quotes, like this:

```
 "title" + "='" + title + "'",
```

Comment: That worked, but Now I've got another issue. 
`title = new String(title.replaceAll("'", ""));` is needed to remove all the apostrophes. They were throwing sql errors as well. This changes my value though, its coming up as no match every time.